# "TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str' " when creating basic calculator(sum only)

Tags: python-3.x

So I get the following error message when running my code:

> TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'

The code itself is:

```
items = []

item = ''


while item != 'done':
    item = (input("Enter value of item or type 'done':"))

    if item != 'done':
        int(item)
        items.append(item)

print('The total of your items is', sum(items))
```

What am I missing or doing wrong in this module? Am I converting to an integer too early/late? I cannot convert it during the initial input because it will not read "done" to finish the calculations. How do I adjust the code to sum my `items` variable without this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is this line:

```
        int(item)
```

Your are converting it correctly, but you are not using the value.

Change it to this:

```
        item = int(item)
```

Comment: Worked perfectly!